# WordPress local install on Mint -need to set global NameServer

Tags: wordpress

Local install of WordPress.  I think I have everything set up to run WP admin install.  I cannot get that page to come up.

I do not know what I am doing.  I am following instructions.  I need more instructions.

First I need to set global nameserver.  How do I do that?
I am using my web host global nameserver.

**Global ServerName**
I contacted my web hosting company for the global server name.
I tried to add that to `apache2.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2.conf
ServerName cp.hosthoot.com
```

I tested with `apachectl configtest` and got:

> AH00558: apache2: could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message. Syntax is okay.

How do I set the global servername?